# Creating accordion functionality in a nested ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items that when one of the items is clicked calls a service, slides down a div and loads into it another list of articles  relating to the item that was clicked. Currently when I click one section and load the content, if I click open another section the content it loads gets entered into every other opened div, how can I avoid this and better handle the accordion functionality?

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="first-row" ng-repeat="problem in problems">
    <div class="user-name-content" ng-click="showEducationResources($index, problem)">
      <div class="summary-symbl">
        <i id="open-icon-{{$index}}" class="cn-plus-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <h4 class="summary-title" ng-bind="problem.Name"></h4>
      <div style="display: none;" id="edu-resources-{{$index}}" >
        <div ng-repeat="document in documentList">
          <div class="edu-doc-preview">
            <p class="edu-doc-title">{{document.topicTitle}}</p>
            <p>{{document.PreviewText}} <a href="#/documentDemo" class="edu-link" title="Read More" ng-click="showEducationDocument(document.HealthwiseURL)">Read More</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="date-stamp" ng-hide="true"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller Code (it's bad...)

```
function getDocumentPreviews(problem) {
    var data = determinCodeSystem(problem);
    Services.GetDocumentPreviewList(data.code, data.system, function(result) {
        if (result.length > 0) {
           $scope.documentList = result;
        } else {
            // TODO: handle empty doc preview
            console.debug("handle empty doc preview");
        }
    }, function(error) {
        console.error("Error occured on GetDocumentPreviewList: " + error);
    });
};

$scope.showEducationResources = function (index, problem) {           
    if (!$('#open-icon-' + index).hasClass('isOpen')) {
        getDocumentPreviews(problem);
    }
    $('#open-icon-' + index).toggleClass('cn-minus-icon').toggleClass('isOpen');
    $('#edu-resources-' + index).slideToggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the opening divs is bound to the same $scope.documentList variable, which causes them to all show the same content, which is why all open divs will change to show the items for the most recently opened one.

You could make $scope.documentList an array or object that stores multiple lists and use index as an accessor. E.g. your inner ng-repeat becomes:

```
<div ng-repeat="document in documentList[$index]">
```

and you set documentList in your controller as:

```
if (result.length > 0) {
  $scope.documentList[index] = result;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to pass the index in to your getDocumentPreviews function.

That will mean you're storing and binding each list separately each time you open a subsequent div.

Comment: Thanks for response, Using your method I get the following error  Cannot set property '0' of undefined  on `$scope.documentList[index] = result;`

Comment: Ah, $scope.documentList needs to be defined.  You can add      $scope.documentList = {}    at the top of your controller code to define it

Comment: oh ok - I see, that makes sense.

Comment: One last question, what would a way to do this same thing with a loading spinner?

Comment: The easiest way would be to div somewhere in page with a gif of a loading spinner and use `ng-show` and/or `ng-hide` which can be bound to a `$scope.loading` variable.  So in your `getDocumentPreviews` function the first thing you do is set `$scope.loading=true` and then set it back to false in the callback function. If your loading spinner div has the tag `ng-show="loading"` it'll show/hide automatically.  You can also have div with `ng-hide="loading"` tag around all your main page content to hide the page and only show the loading spinner whist it's loading.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause it to appear in every open div container with in the ngRepeat though?

Comment: I see, you'd like one inside each div.  I was thinking just one over the whole page.  So you could get that to work in the same was as before by using $scope.loading[index]=true/false to get multiple variables to bind to, and so the loading-spinner gif div then just needs the tag `ng-show="loading[index]"`